# Query returning no results

Tags: query, error

I am trying to update this apex trigger from an earlier thread: [One Primary Ownership on Property](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105132/one-primary-ownership-on-property)

What I want to do seems like it should be simple to me--I simply want it to update the Primary contact field on the Property information with the contact field from the Ownership object. But I am getting an error: `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

I don't understand why this would be happening. It seems like a simple query to me.

```
 trigger primaryContactOwnership on MRG_Ownership__c (after insert,after update) 
    {
        ownerTrigger();

        public void ownerTrigger(){
        List<Id> primaryOwnershipIdList = new List<Id>();
        List<Id> relatedPropertyIdList = new List<Id>();

        for(MRG_Ownership__c ownership : Trigger.New)
        {
            if(ownership.Primary_Contact__c == true && (Trigger.Old == null || Trigger.OldMap.get(ownership.Id) == null 
            || Trigger.OldMap.get(ownership.Id).Primary_Contact__c != true)) // To handle null scenario
            {
                primaryOwnershipIdList.add(ownership.Id);
                relatedPropertyIdList.add(ownership.Property__c);

                Property__c property= [select id, Primary_Contact2__c from Property__c WHERE id =:ownership.Property__r.id limit 1];
                property.Primary_Contact2__c=ownership.contact__c;
                update property;
            }
        }

        List<MRG_Ownership__c> relatedOwnershipList = [Select Id, Primary_Contact__c 
                                                        From MRG_Ownership__c 
                                                        Where Property__c in :relatedPropertyIdList
                                                        And Primary_Contact__c = true
                                                        And Id Not in :primaryOwnershipIdList];

        if(relatedOwnershipList.size() > 0)
        {
            for(MRG_Ownership__c ownership : relatedOwnershipList)
                ownership.Primary_Contact__c = false;

            update relatedOwnershipList;
        }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be with the line:

```
Property__c property= [select id, Primary_Contact2__c from Property__c 
                       WHERE id =:ownership.Property__r.id limit 1];
```

Change it to:

```
Property__c property= [select id, Primary_Contact2__c from Property__c 
                       WHERE id = :ownership.Property__c limit 1];
```

In the trigger context, `ownership.Property__r.id` will likely be null. Hence when the query executes there will be nothing to assign back to property. However, since this is a relationship field you can use the case field to get the Id.

You should probably also:

- Check that `ownership.Property__c` is not null.
- Assign the SOQL query result back to a `List<Property__c>`. You can then check the `size()` of the resulting list. This will avoid the common "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" QueryException that occurs when the query doesn't return any records. See [Using SOQL Queries That Return One Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm)